# Is it legal to have a top-level JPA class that is abstract and does not have a discriminator?

Tags: jpa

For example, is the following top-level JPA class valid:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name = "type",
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
public abstract class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly legal. According specification (JPA 2.0) DiscriminatorValue belongs only to concrete entity class.

Answer (score 0):

I can no no reason why it shouldn't be. Try it out.

The discriminator value of the specified discriminator column will be the entity name of the concrete implementation(s) if the discriminatorvalue annotation has not been specified on the entities (as described in the spec).

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Not really. I am looking for a definitive answer.